# How to accurately determine if a random method is indeed random?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-generation

I wanted to do a project where I measured how random the native RNGs are in various programming languages. How can I objectively measure my results? Also, if you run a random number generate say 100 vs 10,000,000 times should the distribution even out the more tests you run?

I've compared some various methods in Python and here's the results with standard deviation:

- Using secrets module

  - 50 Loops: 0.598
  - 500 Loops: 2.26
  - 5000 Loops: 6.24
  - 50000 Loops: 20.35
- Using random module

  - 50 Loops: 0.51
  - 500 Loops: 2.07
  - 5000: 6.21
  - 50000: 21.15
- Using ridiculously complex hashing method

  - 50 Loops: 1.47
  - 500 Loops: 4.78
  - 5000 Loops: 14.89
  - 50000 Loops: 52.78
- Using num.py method

  - 50 Loops: .57
  - 500 Loops: 2.19
  - 5000 Loops: 6.89
  - 50000 Loops: 20.11

Comment: Partially. I updated my post to include my testing results, I just want to see if those are 'meaningful' or if I should try evaluating a different way.

Comment: What do your numbers represent? How were they calculated?

Comment: Each example generates random numbers between 1 and 100 using various methods within the Python programming language. Then I looped it to see how the results changed. When I ran them 50 times the distribution was pretty even but as I looped longer and longer the distribution becomes more lopsided.

Comment: But how do you get from 50 loops of (how many?) random numbers between 1 and 100 (integers?) to a number like 0.57 as in your bottom bullet list?